# Rewrite rule not working with apache2, lucee tomcat

Tags: .htaccess, apache2, tomcat9, lucee

I have configured server with lucee tomcat and apache2 for virtual host on ubuntu. I have enabled rewrite rule and my virtual host is as followes.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias example.com www.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example.com/

    <Directory /var/www/html/example.com/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error_main_example.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access_main_example.log combined
    DirectoryIndex index.cfm
</VirtualHost>
```

redirect from htaccess file is working good but rewrite rule is not working. Here is the htaccess file that i am trying.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)/abc/([0-9]+)$ /test-404.cfm [L]
```

Here are the example URLs:

```
https://www.example.com/example.cfm/abc/2
https://www.example.com/example.cfm/abc/8
https://www.example.com/example.cfm/abc/15
```

It is showing me tomcat 404 error that

```
HTTP Status 404 – Not Found

Type Status Report

Message The requested resource [/example.cfm/abc/2] is not available

Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.
Apache Tomcat/9.0.35
```

Can any body help me about this issue. By the way, site is configured using classic load balancer on AWS.

Comment: So `/test-404.cfm` was supposed to show a _different_ 404 error message here, or what exactly is the issue?

Comment: @CBroe Yes. Actually test-404 showes some content for these type of URLs. The issue is that it is not rewriting instead it is showing tomcat 404 error.

Comment: The pattern should match the URLs you mentioned. What happens when you remove the other rewriting stuff you got going on before, and leave only this single Rule after RewriteEngine On?

Comment: FYI, enabling rewrite logging can also often help figuring out, what exactly is going on.

Comment: @CBroe. Just found out. The rewrite rule is not applying when url pattern is like this Or for cfm files: /example.cfm/abc/15. But if i use /example.php/abc/15 url. It is rewriting correctly. So apache2 is not considering cfm as file for these type of URLs. Can i define some where?

Comment: @CBroe. Can i rewrite all URLs that is 404 using htaccess?

Answer (score 1):

I'm posting a working solution here also, because you didn't answer to our posts of this cross post at the Lucee forum. This solution might also help others with the same problem.

The issue is that mod_proxy will always preced urlrewrite, unless you invoke mod_proxy with a special urlrewrite rule. To make urlrewrite work and use mod_proxy, you need to flag the rewrite rule with [P] (for proxy). Here is a working example that should work for you:

1. Step: Set everything in apache2.conf in mod_proxy.c as comment, just leaving ProxyPreserveHost and ProxyPassReverse, like so:

```
<IfModule mod_proxy.c>
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        #ProxyPassMatch ^/(.+\.cf[cm])(/.*)?$ http://127.0.0.1:8888/$1$2
        #ProxyPassMatch ^/(.+\.cfml)(/.*)?$ http://127.0.0.1:8888/$1$2
        # optional mappings
        #ProxyPassMatch ^/flex2gateway/(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:8888/flex2gateway/$1
        #ProxyPassMatch ^/messagebroker/(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:8888/messagebroker/$1
        #ProxyPassMatch ^/flashservices/gateway(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:8888/flashservices/gateway$1
        #ProxyPassMatch ^/openamf/gateway/(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:8888/openamf/gateway/$1
        #ProxyPassMatch ^/rest/(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:8888/rest/$1
        ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8888/
    </IfModule>
```

2. Step: In your virtual host configuration set the following rewrite rules ( that may work also in your .htaccess, but I’m not sure).

```
...

<Directory /var/www/html/example.com/>
...
...
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Catch non-existing files/directories and pass them via proxy to a 404 cfml errorpage
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule "^(.*)$" "http://127.0.0.1:8888/my-404.cfm" [P]

# Catch https://www.example.com/example.cfm/abc/2
# Catch https://www.example.com/example.cfm/abc/7 etc.
RewriteRule "^example.cfm(/abc/[0-9]+)$" "http://127.0.0.1:8888/my-404.cfm" [P]

# Pass request for cfm/cfc files to proxy with mod_rewrite rule
RewriteRule  "^(.+\.cf[cm])(/.*)?$" "http://127.0.0.1:8888/$1$2"  [P]

...

 </Directory>
```

I’ve tested it and the solution above works fine.